# Проблема с preg_match php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
$tag = '[&quot;test&quot;,&quot;test1&quot;]';
preg_match('/&quot;(.*)&quot;/', $tag, $match);
$tags = $match[1];
```

Проблема в том, что preg_match убирает символ " только в начале и конце, а к примеру: "," не убирает, в итоге на вывод идёт test","test1.

Comment: А почему str_replace() не подходит? `$tag = str_replace('&quot;', '', $tag)`

Comment: То есть, ты предлагаешь делать str_replace по несколько раз? Строка выглядит так: ["test","test1"], то есть - это делать 3 раза, убирать ", [ и ], лишние строки... Зачем? Ведь есть preg_match, но вот с реализацией проблемы, да и str_replace - Заменяет строку поиска на строку замены

Comment: Вы что-то путаете. `preg_match` ничего не убирает, он только находит в строке подстроки совпадающие с регулярным выражением. Другое дело `preg_replace`

Comment: Нет, почему?! `$tag = str_replace('&quot;', '', $tag)` именно уберет все упоминания `&quot;` в тексте. Все без исключения.

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы вывело test,test1, а не [test,test1]. Так-бы я и не задавал вопрос сюда, но т.к проблема началась в ",". Решил попросить помощи

Comment: Он мне почти выводит так, как я хочу, но проблема идёт в "," между словами, то есть, выводит test","test1...

Comment: Я исправил ответ внизу - кажется он делает то, что тебе нужно

Comment: Опять выдрали с кровью кусок текста из чьего-то html? Удачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исправленный вариант:

```
$tag = '[&quot;test&quot;,&quot;test1&quot;]';
$tag = preg_replace('/(\[|&quot;|\])/', '', $tag);
var_dump($tag);
```

выдаст

```
string(10) "test,test1"
```